# Unwanted padding above top div - only in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am playing around with [this](https://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/) template. When incorporating the functionality into the sort of dashboard I am building, everything works fine except that I get an unwanted empty space of a few px above the tabs, when decreasing the font size. I have created a minimal working example:

HTML:

```
<div class="tab">
  <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
  <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
</div>

<div class="tab">
  <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
  <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #003399;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
}

.tab label {
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tqejgae0/

See the extra blue space above the tabs when using Firefox? It looks as expected in Chromium, Chrome, Opera, and Safari.

There are a lot of similar questions on Stackoverflow, most of them solved with

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Neither this, nor any of the other solutions worked for me.

Web Design is certainly not my background, so I am thankful for any help!

Edit:

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Nope, no extra blue space above the tabs, sorry.

Comment: I can cause at most 1 pixel of blue line to appear above the tabs at certain zoom levels (both above and below 100%) but it's not there at 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding display:block to the .tab label selector solved the problem for me.

```
.tab label {
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tqejgae0/2/

Screenshot:

[image]